# How to rebuild glibc on Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, glibc

It seems like [MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com) is royally screwed up on Linux, because it ["dynamically loads some libs with static TLS"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19268293/matlab-error-cannot-open-with-static-tls), which doesn't mean anything to me other than I get bunches of errors.

The suggested work around is to rebuild `glibc` with a larger `DTV_SURPLUS`. This leaves me with two questions:

- How do I rebuild `glibc` on Arch Linux to increase the `DTV_SURPLUS`? I looked at the PKGBUILD in the abs tree and didn't see `DTV_SURPLUS` anywhere, so I don't know where to make the change.
- What value do I set `DTV_SURPLUS` to be? Presumably, setting it to
  `2^64` would both be overkill and a bad idea.

The issue with MATLAB can be seen with the following MWE in R2014a:

```
>> ones(10)*ones(10);
>> doc('help');
Exception in thread "XPCOMMessageLoop" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /opt/matlab/sys/jxbrowser/glnxa64/xulrunner/xulrunner-linux-64/libxul.so: dlopen: cannot load any more object with static TLS
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.impl.linux.LinuxMozillaToolkit.c(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.impl.linux.LinuxMozillaToolkit.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.MozillaToolkit.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.AppShellXPCOMThread$b.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "XPCOMMessageLoop" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /opt/matlab/sys/jxbrowser/glnxa64/xulrunner/xulrunner-linux-64/libxul.so: dlopen: cannot load any more object with static TLS
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.impl.linux.LinuxMozillaToolkit.c(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.impl.linux.LinuxMozillaToolkit.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.MozillaToolkit.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.AppShellXPCOMThread$b.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "XPCOMMessageLoop" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /opt/matlab/sys/jxbrowser/glnxa64/xulrunner/xulrunner-linux-64/libxul.so: dlopen: cannot load any more object with static TLS
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.impl.linux.LinuxMozillaToolkit.c(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.impl.linux.LinuxMozillaToolkit.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.MozillaToolkit.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.AppShellXPCOMThread$b.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "XPCOMMessageLoop" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /opt/matlab/sys/jxbrowser/glnxa64/xulrunner/xulrunner-linux-64/libxul.so: dlopen: cannot load any more object with static TLS
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.impl.linux.LinuxMozillaToolkit.c(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.impl.linux.LinuxMozillaToolkit.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.MozillaToolkit.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.AppShellXPCOMThread$b.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "XPCOMMessageLoop" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /opt/matlab/sys/jxbrowser/glnxa64/xulrunner/xulrunner-linux-64/libxul.so: dlopen: cannot load any more object with static TLS
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.impl.linux.LinuxMozillaToolkit.c(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.impl.linux.LinuxMozillaToolkit.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.MozillaToolkit.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.gecko.xpcom.AppShellXPCOMThread$b.run(Unknown Source)
```

Where `ones(10)*ones(10);` loads the dynamically linked `libiomp5.so` BLAS library, which seems to not leave enough space for the dynamically linked `libxul.so` required for the HTML based documentation browser. Potentially I can work around this particular MWE by using a patched version of `libiomp5.so`, but the general problem still persists.

Comment: You'd probably be better off checking around to see if there's a distro that has glibc already compiled with a higher DTV_SURPLUS -- perhaps by testing in a VM.

Comment: @goldilocks would a chroot be enough or do I need a full VM?

Comment: I found this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19268293/matlab-error-cannot-open-with-static-tls and this : http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/130558-why-do-i-receive-the-error-blas-loading-error-dlopen-cannot-load-any-more-object-with-static-tls . A Google search after "cannot load any more object with static TLS" is bound to give you more ideas.

Comment: I linked to the SO question in my question and that is where the idea of rebuilding `glibc` was suggested.

Comment: The kernel's not an issue so you could use chroot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To recompile glibc with custom `DTV_SURPLUS` and override the existing version:

1. Copy `/var/abs/core/glibc` to another directory so you can write to it without being root, then `cd` to that directory.
2. Use `makepkg -o` to download and extract the source code without building it(because we will edit the source code before building).
3. Edit `DTV_SURPLUS` located in `src/glibc-<version>/sysdeps/generic/ldsodefs.h`. You may just change the number in the line containing `DTV_SURPLUS`.
4. Build it with `makepkg -e`.
5. Install the custom version with `sudo pacman -U <package file>`. This will override the official package previously installed.

If you don't want to override the existing version, you can use chroot, or maybe LD_PRELOAD will also work.

However, I'm unsure what should `DTV_SURPLUS` be.